# NullPointerException i can´t load a ListView. Two days lost, please help me

Tags: android, listview, nullpointerexception

**LogCat**

```
    02-20 21:43:55.316: E/salida cursor(1564): recorrido finalizado
    02-20 21:43:55.316: D/AndroidRuntime(1564): Shutting down VM
    02-20 21:43:55.316: W/dalvikvm(1564): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception              (group=0x40028a00)
    02-20 21:43:55.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1564): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    02-20 21:43:55.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1564): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start                    activity ComponentInfo{es.garman.waypoints/es.garman.waypoints.ListaLugaresActivity}:    java.lang.NullPointerException
   02-20 21:43:55.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1564):  at   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2781)
   02-20 21:43:55.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1564):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2797)
   02-20 21:43:55.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1564):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:135)
   02-20 21:43:55.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1564):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2132)
   02-20 21:43:55.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1564):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   02-20 21:43:55.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1564):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
   02-20 21:43:55.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1564):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4914)
   02-20 21:43:55.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1564):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   02-20 21:43:55.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1564):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
   02-20 21:43:55.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1564):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
   02-20 21:43:55.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1564):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
   02-20 21:43:55.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1564):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
   02-20 21:43:55.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1564): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
   02-20 21:43:55.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1564):  at es.garman.waypoints.ListaLugaresActivity.cargarLista(ListaLugaresActivity.java:59)
   02-20 21:43:55.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1564):  at es.garman.waypoints.ListaLugaresActivity.onCreate(ListaLugaresActivity.java:34)
   02-20 21:43:55.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1564):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1065)
   02-20 21:43:55.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1564):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2745)
   02-20 21:43:55.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1564):  ... 11 more
   02-20 21:44:30.756: I/Process(1564): Sending signal. PID: 1564 SIG: 9
```

**ListaLugaresActivity.java**

> ```
>  import android.app.Activity;
> import android.app.ListActivity;
> import android.database.Cursor;
> import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
> import android.os.Bundle;
> import android.util.Log;
> import android.view.LayoutInflater;
> import android.view.View;
> import android.view.ViewGroup;
> import android.widget.ListView;
> import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
> import android.widget.TextView;
> public class ListaLugaresActivity extends ListActivity {    
> private BaseDatos db;
> private SQLiteDatabase dbLista;
> Cursor cursor;
> private ListView lista;
> private WaypointRegistro[] datosLista;  
> @Override
> public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.lista_pantalla);      
>     //Abrimos la base de datos 'DBUsuarios' en modo escritura
>     db = new BaseDatos(this, "waypointsDB", null, 1);
>     db.getWritableDatabase();
>     db.close();     
>     cargarLista();
> }
> private void cargarLista() {       
>    dbLista = db.getReadableDatabase();       
>    if (dbLista != null) {         
>       cursor = dbLista.rawQuery("SELECT _id, nombre, lat, lon, descripcion, foto FROM  waypointsDB", null);
>
>       //Nos aseguramos de que existe al menos un registro
>       if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
>          //Recorremos el cursor hasta que no haya más registros
>          datosLista = new WaypointRegistro[cursor.getCount()];
>          int i = 0;
>          do {
>              Log.e("inicio", "do");
>             datosLista[i] = new WaypointRegistro();
>             datosLista[i].setId(cursor.getInt(0));
>             datosLista[i].setNombre(cursor.getString(1));
>             datosLista[i].setDescripcion(cursor.getString(4));
>             i++;
>          } while (cursor.moveToNext());
>          Log.e("salida cursor", "recorrido finalizado");
>          AdaptadorUsuarios adaptador = new AdaptadorUsuarios(this);
>          lista.setAdapter(adaptador);             
>       }
>    }
> }
> @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
> class AdaptadorUsuarios extends ArrayAdapter { 
>     Activity context;
>
>     AdaptadorUsuarios(Activity context) {
>         super(context, R.layout.lista_fila, datosLista);
>         this.context = context;
>     }
>
>     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {   
>
>        View item = convertView;
>        ViewHolder holder;
>        if (item == null) {
>
>           LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
>           item = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lista_fila, null);
>           holder = new ViewHolder();
>           holder.id = (TextView)item.findViewById(R.id.idLista);
>           holder.nombre = (TextView)item.findViewById(R.id.nombreLista);
>           holder.descripcion = (TextView)item.findViewById(R.id.descripcionLista);
>           item.setTag(holder);
>         }else{
>             holder = (ViewHolder)item.getTag();
>         }
>             holder.id.setText(datosLista[position].getId() + "");
>             holder.nombre.setText(datosLista[position].getNombre());
>             holder.descripcion.setText(datosLista[position].getDescripcion());
>         return(item);
>     }
> }
> static class ViewHolder {
>    TextView id;
>    TextView nombre;
>    TextView descripcion;
> }
> }
> ```

**WaypointRegistro.java**

```
public class WaypointRegistro {
private int id;
private String nombre;
private String descripcion;

public WaypointRegistro(){}
public WaypointRegistro(int id, String nombre, String descripcion){
    setId(id);
    setNombre(nombre);
    setDescripcion(descripcion);
}
public int getId() {
   return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
   this.id = id;
}
public String getNombre() {
   return nombre;
}
public void setNombre(String nombre) {
   this.nombre = nombre;
}
public String getDescripcion() {
   return descripcion;
}
public void setDescripcion(String email) {
   this.descripcion = email;
}   

}
```

**lista_fila.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingRight="4dp">
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/idLista"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:padding="3dp"
        />

    </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp">
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/nombreLista"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                />
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/descripcionLista"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**lista_pantalla.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
>
<TextView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:text="@string/txt_tituloLista"
    android:textColor="#FF4201"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    />
<ListView 
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dp">
</ListView>

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/android:empty"
        android:text="@string/txt_empty"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: May be you don't initialize the ListView

Comment: Your code is readable like `das was ich hier sage, denn deine variablen namen sind einfach für keinen verständlich.` As long as you can't understand German, you can't understand me, so how do you expect someone here understanding your variable/class names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are getting NullPointerException because `lista` is null just initialize `lista`  before setting setAdapter :

```
lista=ListaLugaresActivity.this.getListView();
lista.setAdapter(adaptador);
```

Answer (score 1):

`lista` is null.

Add this to your `onCreate()`:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.lista_pantalla);
    lista = getListView();  // <- Add this line
    // ...
```